# MySQL-python error

Tags: mysql-python

I have downloaded MySQL-python connector and installed it using

```
$ sudo python setup.py install.
```

While importing that package from python shell, following error is raised. 
Please help me out.

```
import MySQLdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _mysql
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/_mysql.py", line 23, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/_mysql_api_util.py", line 78, in setup_platform_namespace
ImportError: No module named _mysql_unix.api
```

Answer (score 0):

My installation of `MySQLdb` does not contain a file named `_mysql_api_util.py`. Googleing it suggests it comes from another package named `jaraco.mysql`. Maybe you tried installing that earlier and now it conflicts with `MySQLdb`? Can you uninstall it and try again?

Comment: Yes, i had tried that also but the problem was solved by setting environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a different approach, using the `python-mysqldb` package and the OS package managers.
The installation of MySQLdb is not easily done other way.

**Ubuntu/Debian**: `apt-get install python-mysqldb`

**CentOS/rpm-based**: `yum install mysql-python`

**Fedora**: `dnf install python-mysql`